# QGIS overlay_intersects in geometry generator if points are in polygon

Tags: qgis, overlay, intersect

I have in QGIS v3.22 two layers:

- polygon hex layer
- points layer

I want to create a dynamic view when the points intersect on the polygon layer and fill the polygon content with some color and disappear or make opaque the hexagons with which the points do not intersect.
This dynamic view must be generated in polygon layer Geometry Generator, probaly with **overlay_intersects** expression.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a rule based symbology for your Grid/Polygonlayer and create two rules. One with the expression `overlay_intersects('nameofpointlayer')` and another one with `ELSE`:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: No need to go under "rule-based". You can also go in "categorized" and put overlay_intersects('point layer'). So that you'll have a true/false.