# QGIS count points in polygon geometry generator

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, count

This is a follow up question to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440201/qgis-overlay-intersects-in-geometry-generator-if-points-are-in-polygon).

I have in QGIS v3.22 two layers: polygon hex layer and points layer.

I want to count all the points that overlap with the polygon layer and display the sum of the points. This dynamic view must be generated in polygon layer Geometry Generator and the desired result must visually correspond to this image
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: label expression]

1. Insert this code into `Value` box in the `Layer Styling` tab:

```sql
aggregate(
  layer:='Random points',
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:=1,
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

2. Replace `Random points` with your points layer name.
3. All data must be in one (same) projection.
4. After you add a new point you have to save the edits and update map window (for example move extent).

Result (gif animation):

[image: result gif]

Comment: it counts, but value is "0"

Comment: yes it is "fid" and I changed layer name correctly ... it shows 0 - I see number in the middle of hex, bud it is wrong number. I double cheked this formula also in help

Comment: sorry I can't share data, is there any alternative solution? HEX layer is dublicate layer of original layer. I can share only picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139250/discussion-between-rii-pii-and-comrade-che).

Comment: my data https://dropmefiles.com/fCjqa

Comment: it should also work with `expression:='1'`, no need to worry about an existing or populated field

Comment: @RiiPii make sure both layers have the same projection.

Comment: @RiiPii After reprojection your data to the same CRS - expression works fine.

Comment: thank you guys .. it is so simple ... thumb up